# Custom Control Property in WPF

Tags: wpf, properties, custom-controls

I have a `custom control` for textbox in `wpf` and *I want to assign to it property for enabling and disabling*.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Hi and welcome to So. So we can help you, can you paste the code you have tried so far. this makes it easier for us to see where we can help.

Comment: Can u please explain in detail.